# Applying color to Features in FeatureCollection based on given property value in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, symbology

I have a NYC census track FeatuerCollection in GEE, and I wish to visualize each census track by one of the property columns. How can I assign colors to each feature according to values in a selected property column?

Here is the code I have:

```
var urb = ee.FeatureCollection('users/--------')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-74.18, 40.60, -73.75, 41.00));

Map.addLayer(urb, null, 'layer1');
print(urb);

var Area = urb.aggregate_array("Area");
print(Area);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Please see the Earth Engine Developer Guide section on FeatureCollection visualization: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collections_visualizing